# Python: convert some encoding to russian alphabet

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, mojibake

I have list with unicode

```
lst = [u'\xd0\xbe', u'/', u'\xd0\xb8', u'\xd1\x81', u'\xd0\xb2', u'\xd0\xba', u'\xd1\x8f', u'\xd1\x83', u'\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0', u'____', u'|', u'\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe', u'11', u'search', u'\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82', u'**modis**', u'15', u'\xd0\xa1', u'**avito**', u'\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5', u'[\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbe\xd1\x85\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x91\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f', u'\xd0\x92', u'\xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd1\x91', u'kid', u'google', u'\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8', u'13', u'**\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe**', u'[\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c', u'\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c\xd1\x81\xd1\x8f', u'\xd0\x9e', u'&parent-', u'\xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81', u'###', u'**avito**.', u'**kiddieland**', u'\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd', u'45', u'click2.yandex.ru/redir', u'72']
```

I try to convert some like `u'\xd0\xbe'` to russian.
I tried to use 2 and 3 python, but I can't do that.
I use IDE Pycharm and in settings I have default utf-8. 
When I print that with

```
for elem in lst:
    print (elem)
```

it returns me `Ð¾` for the first elem. When I try `print (elem.encode('cp1252'))`  it returns `b'\xd0\xbe'`
When I use `chardet.detect` it returns me, that it's `utf-8`.
Can anybody explain to me, how can I convert it to russian alphabet and why ways, that I use doesn't fit to get it.

Comment: How did you produce that list in the first place? It contains [Mojibake data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); data decoded as latin-1 or CP1252 while in reality it is actually UTF-8 data.

Comment: You can repair this with manual encoding and decoding, or use the [`ftfy` library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this library helped me. Can you say, if I want to write that to list again, How canI do that? Because after writing to list I get original version

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), incorrectly decoded from UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 or CP1252.

You can repair this by manually reverting that process:

```
repaired = [elem.encode('latin1').decode('utf8') for elem in lst]
```

but be careful; if the data actually was decoded as cp1252 the above would fail if there were any bytes in the range 0x80-0x9f in the source data.

You can use the [`ftfy` library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead; it contains specialist codecs that can handle forced decodings too (where bytes are selectively decoded as Latin-1 where a CP1252 mapping is missing):

```
import ftfy

repaired = [ftfy.fix_text(elem) for elem in lst]
```

`ftfy.fix_text()` does a good job at auto-detecting what codec the data was decoded with.

Either method works for the sample data you gave; using `ftfy` or manually decoding doesn't make a difference for *that specific example*:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> repaired = [ftfy.fix_text(elem) for elem in lst]
>>> repaired
[u'\u043e', u'/', u'\u0438', u'\u0441', u'\u0432', u'\u043a', u'\u044f', u'\u0443', u'\u043d\u0430', u'____', u'|', u'\u043f\u043e', u'11', u'search', u'\u043e\u0442', u'**modis**', u'15', u'\u0421', u'**avito**', u'\u043d\u0435', u'[\u0421\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0451\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f', u'\u0412', u'\u0435\u0449\u0451', u'kid', u'google', u'\u043b\u0438', u'13', u'**\u0430\u0432\u0438\u0442\u043e**', u'[\u041f\u043e\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u0442\u044c', u'\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f', u'\u041e', u'&parent-', u'\u042f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441', u'###', u'**avito**.', u'**kiddieland**', u'\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d', u'45', u'click2.yandex.ru/redir', u'72']
>>> print repaired[20]
[Сохранённая
```

Of course, the *better* solution is to avoid creating a Mojibake in the first place. If you can correct the source of the error, so much the better.

For example, if you loaded this data using the `requests` library and assumed that it was safe to use the `response.text` attribute, then please do read the [*Encodings* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#encodings) of the *Advanced Usage* chapter in the library documentation:

> The only time Requests will not do this is if no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers and the Content-Type header contains text. In this situation, RFC 2616 specifies that the default charset must be ISO-8859-1. Requests follows the specification in this case. If you require a different encoding, you can manually set the `Response.encoding` property, or use the raw `Response.content`.

so if there is character set defined on the response, `response.text` will give you Latin-1 decoded text instead. It is better to avoid using `response.text` and use `response.content` instead in that case and either manually decode or use a format-appropriate parser to determine the codec used (such as BeautifulSoup for HTML).

Comment: Can you say, is it real to replace unicode elements from list to normal values?

Comment: I get this error, when I try parse text from url with `r = requests.get(url)
        page = r.text.encode('utf8').lower()
        text = html2text.html2text(page)
        words = text.split()  for word in words:

            data = []
            count = text.count(word)
            data.append(word)
            data.append(count)
            data = tuple(data)
            lst.append((data))
        dic = dict(lst)`   I count words in this page and next create a dictionary. Can I avoid  Mojibake and get normal strings?

Comment: @PetrPetrov: ah, see, you used `requests.text`! Don't use `response.text` here, it *defaults to Latin-1 when the website doesn't specify a codec*. Use `response.content.decode('utf8')` instead.

Comment: And if you are parsing HTML, consider using `BeautifulSoup` instead and have it autodetect the right encoding from the `response.content` source bytes.

Comment: When I try to split text from page it return me `[u'[![\u044f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441](//yastatic.net/lego/_/la6qi18z8lwgnzdsar1qy1gwcwo.gif)](//www.yandex.ru)', u'#', u'\u043e\u0439...', u'\u043d\u0430\u043c', u'\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043d\u044c', u'\u0436\u0430\u043b\u044c,', u'\u043d\u043e', u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b,', u'\u043f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u0438\u0432\u0448\u0438\u0435', u'\u0441', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0433\u043e', u'ip-\u0430\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0430,', u'\u043f\u043e\u0445\u043e\u0436\u0438']
`

Comment: @PetrPetrov: yes, that's normal, Python containers show objects with `repr()` for debugging purposes and to avoid flooding your screen with control characters; you have a list containing Unicode text. Try printing individual values.

Comment: Is any way to convert that to string? because I should next count words and create a dictionary and it's unclear to see unicode values

Comment: They *are* strings already. You can count words in them and use them in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the elements of your list are byte strings encoded in UTF-8, yet they are of type `str` (or `unicode` in Python 2).

I used the following to convert them back into proper UTF-8:

```
def reinterpret(string):
    byte_arr = bytearray(ord(char) for char in string)
    return byte_arr.decode('utf8')
```

This gives the following, which looks a bit more like Russian:

```
>>> for elem in lst:
...     print(reinterpret(elem))
... 
о
/
и
с
в
к
я
у
на
____
|
по
11
search
от
**modis**
15
С
**avito**
не
[Сохранённая
В
ещё
kid
google
ли
13
**авито**
[Показать
Пожаловаться
О
&parent-
Яндекс
###
**avito**.
**kiddieland**
магазин
45
click2.yandex.ru/redir
72
```

Comment: This assumes that the data was decoded originally as Latin-1. That's not necessarily correct; a CP1252 Mojibake of the same source would give the exact same result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. As all the high-ASCII characters are being escaped in the input strings, why does it matter which encoding was used to produce them? As long as the underlying bytes are valid UTF-8, we can interpret it as such, no?

Comment: The input data didn't include any bytes in the range 0x80-0x9f, but if it did then it would make a big difference here; CP1252 and Latin-1 are exactly the same codecs except for that range, where Latin-1 maps to control codes and CP1252 for the most part maps to different characters further out in the Unicode standard, except for 5 bytes which are *not defined*. A really bad Mojibake decoding would have mapped those to Latin-1 bytes instead, making re-encoding harder.

Comment: When dealing with a Mojibake like this, without anything to distinguish between the various possibilities, the best method is to use ftfy and let *it* figure out what codec to repair this with, so when you let it loose on the full dataset and not just a sample, you still get correct output.

Comment: Sorry, was misreading your previous comment. I think there are some bytes in that range though, for example in the fourth element: `\x81`. As they're all escaped, it doesn't matter in this specific case. Generally it's surely better to use a specialized library, I agree.

Comment: Hrm, and I now see there are a few 0x80-0x9f bytes in there; the OP has already given me the source of the error; they used `requests.get().text` instead of `.content`, so the data was almost certainly decoded as Latin-1. So this is easily avoided.